# Is there a way to make AWS VPN client work on Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, openvpn, aws-vpn

I'm using the AWS VPN Client, it was working OK before upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10 (specifically [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/)). When trying to connect using the AWS VPN client I'm getting a peculiar error - it can't open OpenVPN for some reason? Immediately after clicking "Connect", I'm getting a "Connection Failed. Try again" message. From the logs:

```
 121   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.208 +03:00 [DBG] OvpnGtkServiceClient connected. Calling StartVpnAsync
 122   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.344 +03:00 [DBG] OvpnGtkServiceClient received OpenVPN process PID: -1
 123   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.350 +03:00 [DBG] DeDupeProcessDiedSignals: Unknown error caused OpenVPN process to not start: -1
 124   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.351 +03:00 [WRN] Acs did not stop correctly!
 125   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.351 +03:00 [ERR] Process died signal sent
 126   │ ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnProcessFailedToStartException: Unknown error caused OpenVPN process to not start: -1
 127   │    at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnGtkProcessManager.Start(String openVpnConfigPath, String managementPortPasswordFile, Int32 timeoutMilliseconds) in /home/ubuntu/Jenkins
       │ /workspace/GtkBuild/SecureConnectClient/ACVC.Core/OpenVpn/OvpnProcessManager.cs:line 696
 128   │    at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.Connect(OvpnConnectionProfile configProfile, GetCredentialsCallback getCredentialsCallback, Int32 timeout) in /home/u
       │ buntu/Jenkins/workspace/GtkBuild/SecureConnectClient/ACVC.Core/OpenVpn/OvpnConnectionManager.cs:line 861
 129   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.361 +03:00 [DBG] Received exception for connection state Disconnected. Show error message to user
 130   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.361 +03:00 [ERR] Exception received by connect window view model
 131   │ ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnProcessDiedException: The VPN process has stopped unexpectedly.
 132   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.367 +03:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_GENERAL_ERROR 1 to MetricsTable
 133   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.372 +03:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_GENERAL_ERROR 1 to AnalyticsTable
 134   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.378 +03:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_ATTEMPT_FAIL_VPN_PROCESS_DIED 1 to MetricsTable
 135   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.386 +03:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_ATTEMPT_FAIL_VPN_PROCESS_DIED 1 to AnalyticsTable
 136   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.386 +03:00 [DBG] Clean up connections. Connection state: Connecting
 137   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.399 +03:00 [INF] Validating schema for OpenVPN config: /home/shay/.config/AWSVPNClient/OpenVpnConfigs/dev
 138   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:01.444 +03:00 [DBG] Inserted event CONNECTION_PROFILE_TYPE 1 to AnalyticsTable
 139   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.402 +03:00 [DBG] Caught exception when getting connection status. Exception information: System.TimeoutException: The message did not respond w
       │ ithin the expected timeframe or was cancelled
 140   │    at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.SendMessage(String message, Int32 timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/workspace/Gtk
       │ Build/SecureConnectClient/ACVC.Core/OpenVpn/OvpnConnectionManager.cs:line 1140
 141   │    at ACVC.Core.OpenVpn.OvpnConnectionManager.GetConnectionStatus() in /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/workspace/GtkBuild/SecureConnectClient/ACVC.Core/OpenVpn/OvpnConnection
       │ Manager.cs:line 1228
 142   │    at ACVC.Core.Metrics.MetricsClient.RecordBytesMetricsAndAnalytics(IConnectionManager connectionManager) in /home/ubuntu/Jenkins/workspace/GtkBuild/SecureConnect
       │ Client/ACVC.Core/Metrics/MetricsClient.cs:line 136
 143   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.421 +03:00 [DBG] Inserted event UI_APP_VPN_CONNECT_GENERAL_ERROR 0 to MetricsTable
 144   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.423 +03:00 [INF] Terminating connection
 145   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.423 +03:00 [WRN] Acs did not stop correctly!
 146   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.424 +03:00 [DBG]  Ending connection details reporting.
 147   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.425 +03:00 [WRN] We are calling GracefulKill in a method that is not supposed to change Connection state.
 148   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.426 +03:00 [DBG] GracefulKill
 149   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.429 +03:00 [DBG] Stopping openvpn process
 150   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.429 +03:00 [DBG] Sending SIGTERM to gracefully shut down the OpenVPN process
 151   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.429 +03:00 [DBG] Cancelling socket listen token
 152   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.430 +03:00 [DBG] Dispose socket
 153   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.430 +03:00 [DBG] Calling StopVpnAsync of GTK OpenVPN service to kill orphaned OpenVPN processes in case graceful shutdown failed
 154   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.442 +03:00 [DBG] OvpnGtkServiceClient connected. Calling StopVpnAsync
 155   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.587 +03:00 [DBG] OvpnGtkServiceClient stopped OpenVPN process successfully? True
 156   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.588 +03:00 [DBG] Release process manager lock
 157   │ 2022-04-12 01:00:02.589 +03:00 [DBG] Disconnected
```

I've reached out to support and they were unhelpful. I'm running Pop!_OS 21.10. I can run `openvpn` and `openvpn3` locally on my terminal.

Anyone experiencing this issue and has any idea?

Comment: maybe [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1013797/aws-vpn-client-connection-to-new-vpc-endpoint-is-failing) question can help you? (it has same exception, Even though its on windows)

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried all these things and they were unhelpful

Comment: I'm not able to use the AWS VPN Client on Ubuntu 22.04, but my issue is when I click in the app to add a profile, it crashes and then won't open again until I do a reboot. As for your issue, it might be worth downgrading OpenVPN to the version that comes with Ubuntu 20.04. I suspect my issue is related to the new version of GNOME that comes with 22.04...

Comment: I'm having issues with the R Studio GUI as well, it's likely apps need to be updated to work with the latest release of GNOME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the workaround: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406567/amazon-workspaces-client-not-working-on-22-04

The answer no longer works, but you just have to use the latest libssl available. Today this works:

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.21_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libssl1.1_1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.21_amd64.deb
```

If you see a "Permission Denied" error during the second step, you can ignore it.

Also works on Ubuntu 22.10.

Comment: Thanks! That did work for other team members - I switched to MacOS for unrelated reasons anyways. 